# Sort based on number rather than time

Tags: java

I have several thousand lines that look like this (with different numbers obviously):

```
9994 ms - Total Recall DVD: 
99945 ms - classical music: 
99946 ms - ruth rendell: 
99949 ms - house beautiful january 1964: 
9995 ms - Killing Lincoln: 
9995 ms - TITLE:THE INTERCEPT AND AUTHOR:Wolf: 
9995 ms - TITLE:the amazing spiderman: 
9995 ms - everywhere russo: 
9995 ms - treasure yourself: 
9995 ms - what to expect when you're expecting: 
99952 ms - building endurance: 
9996 ms - Number the stars: 
9996 ms - The son of neptune: 
9996 ms - forsate saga, Narrowed By: LIBRARY:
```

If I read this file into java, what is the best way to sort this by query time?

Comment: What are you having trouble with.  I assume you want to preserve order if the time stamps are the same.

Comment: What's the file type (txt, xml, doc, xls, .....)?

Comment: what do you mean by "number rather than time"? as in you want 9994 ms followed by 9995 ms, or you want it sorted like in your example?

Comment: Example: 99949 ms .... should not come before 9995 ms...
I have tried reading everything into a list then using "sort" on it, that is what you see above. This is a .log file (text)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you're dealing with the file just as *strings*, you'll get lexicographic ordering. That's not what you want.

I would strongly suggest that as you read the file in, you parse each line into a full entry. After that, it should be easy to create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which compares based on time (whether you store the number of milliseconds as a `long` or using something like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)'s `Duration` type). While you *could* make the class (`Album` or whatever) implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparable.html) instead, I don't think there's a "natural" sort order here - it makes sense to be able to sort by various different comparisons in different situations. Just pass the `Comparator` into [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and you'll be fine.

In general, I'd recommend converting data from text into a "fuller" object model as early as possible, and then keeping the data in the richer format for as long as possible. While you're dealing with data as just strings, you'll suffer from exactly this sort of problem... whereas when you've got rich data, all kinds of things are much easier.

Apply this principle (working with the "natural" type of your data, instead of just a string representation, for as much of the time as possible) throughout your code. It will make your life a lot simpler. Avoid conversions where possible using JDBC parameters etc, and make each variable really mean what it says :)

Comment: I can do that, I was just hoping there was an easier way. Thanks.

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey: You *could* write a `Comparator` which handles the strings directly, but given that you'll probably want the rest of the information anyway, you'd be much better off separating the two tasks (parsing and comparing).